# Anonymous callback function to JsObject doesn't update Dart Controller until after a user action

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-js-interop

Given the dart code

```dart
class LandingController {
  bool hideDiv = false;

  void doit() {
      new JsObject(context['loginControls']).callMethod('fadeLogin', [() {
         print(hideDiv);
         hideDiv = true;
         print(hideDiv);
         print("WTF");
      }]);
  }
}
```

which calls the JS:

```dart
var loginControls = function() {
  this.fadeLogin = function(func) {
    $('#landingHeader').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, func);
  }
};
```

which should affect the view:

```dart
<button ng-click="doit();">Click</button>
<div id="landingHeader">Hide me after button click</div>
<div ng-if="ctrl.hideDiv == false"><img src="assets/img/ajax-loader-small.gif">Waiting for div to disappear...</div>
```

After a button click and a 500 millisecond delay I see in my console a "WTF" print correctly. The `div`, however, is still visible. Once a user action occurs, in my case a mouse click, the `div` magically disappears. It seems as though the controller's value is changed, but the browser doesn't receive the change to hide the div, as I've printed the controller's value in the anonymous callback.

There is a work around, but it involves setting Dart timer's to the same fade times that you use in the javascript after the `JsObject` call and setting your controller's values in those Timer callbacks - gross but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `scope.apply()`. I think Angular just can't recognize the value change in `hideDiv` when `doit()` is called from another zone (like JS).

You usually don't need to call `scope.apply()` in Angular.dart but I think this is one of the exceptions.

Is the `animate` function the only reason you use `jQuery`? It might be easier to do this with Angular.darts animation features.

Comment: This worked. Very silly of me to forget about `scope.apply()`, but I constantly do. Hope this helps someone.

As an aside, while I'm currently only using it for animations this is just a mock site and may be expanded in the future. I did some research on this and found [the pub package for animations](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/animation) but the missing features section drew me away from it.

Comment: You know about Angular.darts own animation support? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqilB8nJ6gE

Comment: Well damn. Looks like I have some refactoring to do! Thanks!!